# Solid colours with no shading

Tags: shaders, lighting

Im trying to make an image sequence of a scene with solid colours and no lighting effects. I need each object to keep its HEX value I assigned to it as I'm transferred the image to an AI. The problem I am facing is the render seems to produce a slightly different hex value which is confusing the AI.
The method I was trying was to create a scene with only emission shaders but the emission seems to darken or brighten the value.

Any solutions to assigning true HEX values to an object with no shadows/ lighting effects (almost like cell shading)

Cheers

AI colours:

[image]

Blender render (same hex value with emission shader):

[image]

Comment: are you sure the Render > Color Management > View Transform is set on Standard and not Filmic?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Standard combined with a transparent background solved the issue. World material was changing the colours of the objects in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Standard combined with a transparent background solved the issue. World material was changing the colours of the objects in the scene